# Can't read all lines in file that being used by another process

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to read all lines of log file that being used by some program.

When I tried to do it I am receiving exception:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled  : file used by another process
```

So I searched on the web and found number of solutions:
[C# exception. File is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957309/c-sharp-exception-file-is-being-used-by-another-process)
[Read log file being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942717/read-log-file-being-used-by-another-process)
[What's the least invasive way to read a locked file in C# (perhaps in unsafe mode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560651/whats-the-least-invasive-way-to-read-a-locked-file-in-c-sharp-perhaps-in-unsaf)
[C# The process cannot access the file ''' because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803929/c-sharp-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-anoth)
[File is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737444/file-is-being-used-by-another-process)
http://coding.infoconex.com/post/2009/04/21/How-do-I-open-a-file-that-is-in-use-in-C

The common solutions are to use `using` to wrap the `FileStream` and add the `FileShare.ReadWrite`.

I tried those solutions but I am still receiving the exception that the file is being used by another process.

In my below code I open the file `D:\process.log` to make the file used (**for testing**) and then trying to open the file.
The exception is on row:

```
 using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(i_FileNameAndPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

**CODE:**

```
 private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        DialogResult dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
          listView.Items.Clear();
          File.Open(@"D:\process.log", FileMode.Open);  //make the file being used
          String fileNameAndPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
          String[] fileContent = readAllLines(fileNameAndPath);
        }
}

private String[] readAllLines(String i_FileNameAndPath)
{
    String[] o_Lines = null;
    int i = 0;
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(i_FileNameAndPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            while (streamReader.Peek() > -1)
            {
                String line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                //o_Lines[i] = line;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return o_Lines;
}
```

Comment: all of that is of no use if that other process is exclusively locking the file

Comment: Can't you just use `File.ReadAllLines` ?

Comment: Its likely that the other process that is creating the log file has locked the file so that other processes cannot read it. You can't do anything about this while the log file handle is being used. You can only process that log file after it has been closed.

Comment: @T.S. I can and I did but it works only if the file is not being used.
My problem is when I want to read the lines of file that is being used

Comment: @KerryKobashi but I can open this log file with notepad or notepad++ so if these programs can open it, it not locked.

Comment: Try changing the FileShare to FileShare.None

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use an overload of File.Open in your menuclick event handler like this:

```
File.Open(@"C:\process.log", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

The last param is a value specifying the type of access other threads have to the file.

see [this article from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.File.Open);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: Did it and now it works, Thanks :).
Instead of: 
 using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(i_FileNameAndPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
   
I wrote what you wrote.