# Code Execution stops with no error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

In my `Form1_Load` event, the code execution stops for no reason the middle of nowhere, and just finishes the loading process at that instance, showing the gui, this is the code and the line where it stops:

```
Downloadn("https://somelinkhere.com/file.txt","Init.txt");
        Application.DoEvents();
        List<string> links = new List<string>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Init.txt"); //Code Stops and Gui Shows up after executing this code
        links.Add(lines[0].Split('^')[1]);
        links.Add(lines[1].Split('^')[1]);
        links.Add(lines[2].Split('^')[1]);
        links.Add(lines[3].Split('^')[1]);
```

The debugging process shows no errors, what could i be doing wrong ?

Comment: So you set a breakpoint on that line (or somewhere before), pushed `F11` once on that line and the program stops debugging with no errors?

Comment: Why are you reading a file on load? You say GUI shows after executing the line, what did you think would happen?

Comment: I wonder if an exception is being caught and swallowed somewhere, since by the sounds of it the program doesn't crash it merely skips some code. In VS, go to Debug\Exceptions, tick all the Thrown boxes and try again. If already ticked or that doesn't help, let us know.

Comment: What am i showing here, is only a part, it should keep step debugging, not stop debugging and show the gui, i expect it to go through the rest of the code.

Comment: Is the code above in a `try-catch`? If not, place it inside one and see what happens.

Comment: @StephenKennedy your comment helped me show up the exception, which was `System.IO.IOException`, aka the infamous Already being used error, any way to over come it ?

Comment: In that case I've promoted my comment to an answer. Wrt to the second question, the obvious remedy is to ensure the file is not locked. However I think there might be a way to tell it to open up readonly. I'll check the docs.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27771453/397817 If no help, it probably needs to be a new question as I've resolved the issue of why code was being skipped. Hope that helps! Please let me know if it does or not!

Comment: I just added a dispose function to the WebClient at the end and it worked, thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if an exception is being caught and swallowed somewhere, since by the sounds of it the program doesn't crash it merely skips some code. In Visual Studio, go to Debug\Exceptions, tick all the Thrown boxes and try again. If my suspicion is correct, this will identify the problem.

Comment: yep, in the new VS 2015, not all the exception handlers are enabled (checked)