# JSON in body of POST then extract the body of the response to get the access_token

Tags: c#

I have this small Python application that I wrote last year that I need to remake in C#. I don't really know C#, but need to make a connection between Dynamics 365 and QuickBooks Desktop which uses C# (or C++, Java, VB... none of which I know).

As I said, the Python app works fine, and I get what I need from D365 via Postman, put having a hell of time getting it working for C#. There is a sample project [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-query-data-sample-csharp), but trying to interpret what is going on is making my head spin (it doesn't run either otherwise I'd just use it).

This is what I currently do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConnectToCRM();
    }

    static void ConnectToCRM()
    {
        string crmOrg = "https://company.api.crm.dynamics.com";
        string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string clientSecret = "super_secret_stuff";
        string username = "me@company.biz";
        string userPassword = "password";
        string authorizationEndPoint =
            "https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize";
        string crmWebApi = "https://company.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2";

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"client_id", clientId},
                {"client_secret", clientSecret},
                {"resource", crmOrg},
                {"oauthUrl", authorizationEndPoint},
                {"username", username},
                {"password", userPassword},
                {"grant_type", "password"}
            };

        HttpRequestToCrm(values);
    }

    public class ServerResponse
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string ext_expires_in { get; set; }
        public string expires_on { get; set; }
        public string not_before { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    }

    static async void HttpRequestToCrm(Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        string tokenEndPoint = "https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token";

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, content);
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent);

            ServerResponse rb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(responseContent);

            Console.WriteLine(rb.token_type);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("catch");

            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it I need to be using `FormUrlEncodedContent` for `x-www-form-urlencoded`, as `x-www-form-urlencoded` is what I have to do in Postman for it to work. Python just seems to be doing it.

`Console.WriteLine(content);` just says `System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent`. The `Console.WriteLine(response);` actually has something in it now, where it didn't before: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage]`. I need to get the response body, so that I can get the`access_token` and then finally actually query the D365 web API.

How do I get the response body and the access_token? How do I even see that that is what it is responding with? Is my approach entirely wrong?

**EDIT:**

Whether or not I do:

`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, content);`

Or:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, content);
```

Visual Studio Community 2017 quits running at that line and doesn't trigger any kind of error. I'll sent a break point there, then F10 or F11, and it exits the program.

Found this regarding it:

[Code Execution stops with no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683711/code-execution-stops-with-no-error)

Turned on all the options, but still can't see why it is just ending.

This is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do working in Postman. I'm obviously just doing something wrong in C#.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the Content of the Response:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, content);

if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return; // optional

string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

First of all you need to `await` the `PostAsync()` call. Since this only leaves you with a `HttpResponseMessage` then and not the actual content of the response, you'd have to get it in a second step by reading the response's Content Property as a string.

If your Response returned an OK (HTTP 200 Status Code) this code should leave you with `responseContent` holding the desired response as a string.

I assume that your `access_token` is a JSON Property in this received string, so you would have to then deserialize it or use a extracting mechanism to get the actual `access_token` from said string. There are already plenty of posts on StackOverflow regarding this, so i won't elaborate on it any further.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have updated my question based on testing your suggestion.

Comment: @sockpuppet Just a quick heads up, you're doing this in a console right? The Console will close/the process end once the code block in the `Main` method is finished. SInce `ConnectToCRM` calls the async method `HttpRequestToCrm` the code in `Main` finishes before the async method finishes. So your process shuts down before your async method is completed. Adding a `Console.ReadLine();` after the `ConnectToCRM();` call should keep the console open/the process running. Let me know if this was the issue!

Comment: Hey, there it is! Everything I was trying to get. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sockpuppet no problem :) Most of the times the issue lies in places we least expect it!

Answer (score 1):

Couple things right off the bat, you aren't `await`ing your `PostAsync` call so you don't really have the response stored.

Second, C# doesn't automatically serialize objects like that when you tell it to write to the console so it is just telling ou what kind of object it is, aka a task that is wrapping an `HttpResponseMessage`.

The following should get you the response body (assuming it is just the token this will work fine for you). You'll need to modify it some to work perfectly for you, but this should get you started.

```
try
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndPoint, content);
    //read the response body as a string here
    string token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(response);

}
catch (WebException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("catch");

    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have updated my question based on testing your suggestion.